# Free provisioning profile not visible in latest Visual Studio 2019 (works on VS4Mac on Mac)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

For the life of me I cannot make Visual Studio 2019 (16.7.6) to display my **FREE provisioning profile**. Note I do not have a paid subscription.

[image]

**It works perfectly in Visual Studio on Mac and XCode.**

**I was able to deploy to my device both a native app in XCode and from VS4Mac on my Mac, I do use the same bundle id**

I tried everything in Visual Studio on Windows I think:

- connecting and disconnecting from the Mac
- restarted Visual Studio
- forgetting the Mac and reconnecting back to it

Frustrating!

The documentation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows does not mention any possible issues.

Some time ago this used to work with no issues, I was able to deploy on my device from VS on Windows with no problems!

Comment: Try to click `Tools - Options - Xamarin - Apple Accounts` to see if the `Apple Id` exists,if it exist,click `View Details` to see if the provisioning  exists in the list.You could show a screenshot of it.

Comment: I mentioned in my question I do not have a paid Apple developer account. Trying to add a non-paid account in the Visual Studio Xamarin settings ends up with an error dialog saying "There was an error trying to log in: An active membership to the Apple Developer Program is required to provision iOS devices for deployment"

Comment: That setting is only for automatic provisioning. See the link in my question to the Xamarin documentation.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Could you please bring some attention to my question from your collegues at Xamarin? This is still a problem for me, I cannot make it work in Visual Studio

Comment: I have talk with my collegues at Xamarin,He has the same issue and suggests you go straight to the VS forum.

Comment: Thanks, so what's the solution? Is there a post somewhere I can read with a solution?

Comment: @DonBox Unfortunately, there is no good workaround now.  I'm so sorry that the inconvenience that it must have caused you. We could look forward to the next version of Visual Studio.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT There's no way to at least debug this issue to try to see what's the actual issue? Are there any logs to try check?

Comment: @DonBox Last day, I have updated the version of **Xcode** to `12.1` of my Mac, I found that **Visual Studio** (`16.7.6`) could see my free apple account. You could update to the lastest version to have a try.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I have XCode 12.1 too but it still doesn't work, the "Signing Identity" combo-box in VS 16.7.6 still only shows "Developer (Automatic)" and "Distribution (Automatic)".

Comment: @DonBox Okey, the provisioning file also not shows in my local site, but whether it could run in physical device if choosing the Automatic option?

Comment: Is there any progress in here? I am facing the same issue?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT It seems to work most of the time, it deploys OK when using the Automatic, even if the dropdowns say theres no matching profile. But I am getting sometimes the error saying there's no matching profile and I cannot deploy.

Comment: @DonBox Okey, you could have a try with modifying the app bundle ID with new special one to check whether can generate the matching profile automatically each time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant using Manual Provisioning, even if it says Provisioning Profile: No matching profiles found, it can still sometimes deploy to device. 
I'm not on VS 2018 16.8.0 and it still doesn't work. This is very disappointing.